# grails- 2.3.4 generate-all command is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

I am new to Grails Framework. I took Grails-2.3.4 version to develop the application.
I Created the domain class `test.User` and I ran the command `generate-all`.

Immediately the following error got occurred. Command is `grails generate-all test.User`

```
2013-12-07 00:27:12,703 [Thread-8] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [domainClass:2.3.4] could not reload changes to file [F:\Workspace\ggts\TestApp\grails-app\domain\test\User.groovy]: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
   [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
   [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
Message: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
    [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
```

I searched this problem in different forum. I was not able get the correct solution. I official Grails site they mention the it was fixed in grails-2.3.4 version. but still i'm facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the fork mode?  That has caused issues in 2.3.4.  Has this worked in an older version?  Maybe your package of test. is causing an issue.

```
// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: false,//test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run:false,//run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
```